# Order nodes via drag 'n drop

Tags: views

I'm looking for an easy way for my clients to re-arrange the order of nodes.
When creating a content type I added a "weight" field for them to change, but of course with a lot of content this is a lot of work.

Is there any module that allows drag 'n drop to change the order of nodes being displayed in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module is just the module for this job.

Answer (score 2):

I think [DraggableViews](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) is what you are looking for. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... makes rows of a view "draggable" which means that they can be rearranged by Drag'n'Drop.
>
> Have you ever rearranged Blocks, sorted Taxonomy terms or reordered Menu items at the Drupal administration pages? All these pages use the tabledrag.js javascript that enables Drag'n Drop on HTML-tables.
>
> With DraggableViews you can apply this tabledrag.js to any [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)-generated table.

Comment: That seems only to work for tables though